# React JS webpack-dev-server api cannot be called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babel-loader

I've built my app in React and after testing it in the production build through the webpack-dev-server, the impossibility of calling the API shows up. 
I'm making the requests through AXIOS.

The following error occurs for GET request:

GET http://localhost:8080/api/web/api/get-logged-navbar 404 (Not Found)

For the POST requests, it doesn't trigger the actions.

Even though I'm using the correct path for the request.

My app's important folders are structured as such:

- public (the bundle.js built file, as well as other styling and script assets are in here)
- src (components and actions)
- api (the api code is in here: Yii2)

Webpack config:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'public');
var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src');

var config = {
  entry: APP_DIR,
  output: {
    path: BUILD_DIR,
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        include: APP_DIR,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loaders: ["style-loader","css-loader"]
      },
    ]
  }
};

module.exports = config;
```

Do I need to set up a proxy and put the API on another server port?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're saying what I think you're saying, then yes, you probably need webpack-dev-server's [proxy option](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-proxy) to forward your API requests to your Yii2 backend. Find out what port the API server is listening on and proxy `/api` to that port as in the example on that page.

Answer (score 0):

I built a weather app that used React/Webpack and Axios to make API calls to openweather.org I wouldn't think that a proxy would be necessary. You should investigate the URL you are passing to Axios. Without being able to see your code, it would be hard to make further suggestions.

Comment: When passing the URL to axios in the developer environment, everything's working just fine. Only when I get to the production environment, do the errors show up.